# jstree adding checkbox plugin causes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, checkbox, jstree

I'm using the jstree jquery plugin to build a tree with ~330 nodes in 3 different levels.

When I add the checkbox plugin to add checkboxes to each tree node, I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined.

The div where the tree is set to appear just shows a Loading message.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    buildTreeJson((testTree) => {
        $(function() {
            $('#jstreetest').jstree({
                "core": {
                    "data": testTree,
                    "themes": {
                        "variant": "large"
                    }
                },
                "checkbox": {
                    "keep_selected_style": false
                },
                "plugins": ["themes", "checkbox", "changed"]
            });
        });
    });

...
```

Removing the checkbox plugin I have no issues.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what your data looks like?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was an issue with the data being cyclic that I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Just like OP I found out that my data being **cyclic** was causing this:

> Sorry for the delay, it was an issue with the data being cyclic that I
>   overlooked.